# Perforce+Sonar setup for New line code coverage

Tags: version-control, perforce, sonarqube

I am trying to find out code coverage on new lines only. I use jacoco report for IT coverage and run mvn sonar:sonar. Sonar does not display the new line code coverage.
I am not sure what configuration I am missing.It seems to work for svn repo. I run mvn sonar on the base version and again with the latest version.
I am using Perforce,SonarQube 4.4, SCM Activity Plugin 1.8.
Here is my POM.xml,

```
<scm>
<connection>scm:perforce:username@perforceserver:portnumber://depot</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:perforce:username@perforceserver:portnumber://depot</developerConnection>
<url>scm:perforce:username@perforceserver:portnumber://depot</url>
</scm>
<properties>
<skipTests>false</skipTests>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
<sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>C:/SonarData/ExecFiles/CSMmergeddata.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
<sonar.scm.reloadBlame>true</sonar.scm.reloadBlame>
<sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
</properties> 
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${acme-corporate-pom.sonarVersion}</version>
</plugin>
```

...

Comment: Does the tool produce a log file when it runs? Have you looked in that file?

Comment: I checked the log and found following :
SCM provider not found
I am finding coverage between specified version and latest version.But always latest version considered for analysis , thus i guess no new line coverage found

Answer (score 1):

To have code coverage on new line information, SonarQube relies on information from the SCM engine. As you can see on the [SCM Activity plugin matrix](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin), Subversion is perfectly supported but not Perforce - which is only known to be tested by some users but not formally validated by SonarQube team as "supported".

So either:

- your configuration of the SCM Activity plugin is not correct

  - See the "Additional configuration for Perforce" section of [the documentation of this plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin)
- or you hit a bug in the implementation of the Maven SCM library (we know there are some bugs)

  - See all the [open bugs](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-496?jql=project%20%3D%20SCM%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20component%20%3D%20maven-scm-provider-perforce%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC) on this lib

Comment: I checked out the code of specific revision and the latest revision for analysis. In sonar I drilled down to the code and found that always the latest code is considered for SCM. How can I mention to consider the specified version for analysis.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.